# Mobx-state-tree create form with types.identifier field on model

Tags: mobx, mobx-state-tree

I've started using mobx-state-tree recently and I have a practical question.

I have a model that has a `types.identifier` field, this is the database id of the resource and when I query for existing stuff it gets populated.

When I am creating a new instance, though, following the [example that Michel has on egghead](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-create-an-entry-form-to-add-models-to-the-state-tree), I need to pass an initial `id` to my `MyModel.create()` on initial state, however, this ID will only be known once I post the creation to the API and get the resulting created resource.

I have searched around for a simple crud example using mobx-state-tree but couldn't find one (suggestions?).

What is the best practice here? Should I do a `MyModel.create({ id: 'foobar' }) and weed it out when I post to the API (and update the instance once I get the response from the API)?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, 3 years later, and can't find a solution...
I wish I could define a field as `id: types.maybe(types.identifier)`, but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of mobx-state-tree's current design. [Identifiers are immutable](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/issues/887).

One strategy I've seen to get around this issue is to store your persistence layer's `id` in a separate field from your `types.identifier` field. You would then use a library like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to generate the `types.identifier` value:

```
import { v4 } from "node-uuid"
const Box = types
    .model("Box", {
        id: types.identifier,
        name: "hal",
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    })
const box = Box.create({ 'hal', 10, 10, id: v4() })
```